# Convert navigation to vertically

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I just test a ASP.MVC 2 project. Please see the image.
[image]

The relevant CSS:

```
/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;

    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li
{

   list-style: none;

 }

 ul#menu li a
{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #034af3;
}

 ul#menu li a:hover
 {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul#menu li a:active
  {
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul#menu li.selected a
  {
     background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
   }
```

I want to convert it from horizonal to vertically, what I tried was to remove each block and test but no lucky.

The html:

```
<body>
<div class="page">

    <div id="header">


        <div id="logindisplay">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
        </div> 

        <div id="menucontainer">

            <ul id="menu">              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
            </ul>
         <div id="title">
            <h1>WSTEST</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul#menu li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Originally is `display: inline`, change it to `display: block;` and it should work

Hope it helps!

Comment: Use `position: relative;` on `ul#menu` and remove all the `float` properties you could have added.

Comment: @Love I downloaded your example and menu looks vertical

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the text-align:right;

I'm surprised that there is nothing in your code telling the LI elements that they are floated as that's the normal way to create a horizontal menu.

I sus[ect there may be a float:left being added to the LI elements somewhere else.

Comment: Try this:

    ul#menu li, ul#menu li a { float:none; }

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website so we can see the whole thing?